# Gentelella Template Dynamic Data Search Results

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dynamic, automation, gentelella

I am using the following Gentelella template for displaying the results of my automation. There is a progress bar that updates each time automation progresses however this requires page to be rendered again. So when I want to use the search bar and look for a specific automation progress result disappears seconds after appearing because page gets rendered again. This problem is mainly because example template use static data whereas I use dynamic data how can I adapt my code so my dynamic data doesn't cause any issues with the search bar?

https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/gentelella

https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/tables_dynamic.html#

I wanted to see the results of the specific automation progress after I input the specific name into the search bar without results disappearing seconds after it is displayed.